# how to override custom auto-configurations?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have made a auto-configuration class for my project to connect to AWS Sqs. This class is working fine but when I try to override auto-configuration functionality, I am getting autowire error from calling code. Please guide if my implementation of auto-configuration class is right?

I tried different @Conditional annotations to find the solution but its not working out.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(AwsSqsAsyncClient.class)
public class AwsSqsAsyncAutoConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "aws.sqs.queue-type", havingValue = "fifo")
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(AwsSqsProperties.class)
    static class AwsFifoSqsAsyncAutoConfigurationBuilder{

        private final AwsSqsProperties awsSqsProperties; //another class defined by me for properties

        @Inject
        public AwsFifoSqsAsyncAutoConfigurationBuilder(AwsSqsProperties awsSqsProperties) {
            this.awsSqsProperties = awsSqsProperties;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public AwsSqsAsyncClient fifoAsyncClient() {
            return AwsSqsFactory.createAwsSqsAsyncClient(AwsSqsMessageRequestFactory
                    .createAwsSqsFifoRequestFactory("producer-application-name", awsSqsProperties.getQueueUrl()),
                                awsSqsProperties.getAccessKey(), awsSqsProperties.getSecretKey());

        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am trying to override auto-configuration functionality

```
@Configuration
public class AmazonSQSConfig {

    @Bean
    public AwsSqsAsyncClient amazonSqsAsyncClient(){
        return  AwsSqsFactory
                .createAwsSqsAsyncClient(AwsSqsMessageRequestFactory
                                .createAwsSqsFifoRequestFactory("someother-producer-application-name",
                                        "some amazon url"), "access key",
                        "secret key");
    }
}
```

calling code, this is where I am trying to autowire and getting error 
"Could not autowire. there is more than one bean of type  AwsSqsAsyncClient
Beans: amazonSqsAsyncClient 
and fifoAsyncClient "

```
private final AwsSqsAsyncClient awsSqsClient;

 @Autowired
 public SQSPublisherImpl(AwsSqsAsyncClient awsSqsClient) {
     this.awsSqsClient = awsSqsClient;
 }
```

Spring boot factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.aws.starter.sqs.AwsSqsAsyncAutoConfiguration
```

I expect autoconfiguration to get disabled when I define my bean for AwsSqsAsyncClient in calling code

Comment: Please show your `spring.factories` file.

Comment: you should add @Qualifier before autowiring an overriden bean. If you are using spring > 2.0.2 - try setting spring-main-allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

Comment: But since calling code has own implementation of AwsSqsAsyncClient i.e through amazonSqsAsyncClient(), why @qualifier is reqd. This should disable Auto-configuration functionality.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but to prevent further problems: Check the naming of the parameter in the builder constructor (parameter name is `atlasAwsSqsProperties`, but you don't use that in the assignment in the constructorbody).

Comment: is your spring factories config definitely in `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`? I also think that since your bean is configured in an inner static class (in your auto configuration) that is why it is not working, because in spring.factories you're using the outer class name. Try move all that to the top level class and see if that helps.